# Javascript Mediasource play video and audio simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, media-source

I want to play audio and video simultaneously using Media Source in Javascript.
I can play either but not both at the same time.

Here's my code so far:

```
 let mse = function() {
    if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(codecs)) {
        a = new MediaSource();
        a.addEventListener('sourceopen', ma);
        return a;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}();
```

I have another 600 lines of code, if needed.

Comment: Relevant information would be what codecs you're using, what container, what error you're getting, and whether or not static media works outside of MSE on that browser.  (Also... what browser?)

Comment: i told you my code is fine , and thank you i get the answer any way

Comment: "I get the answer any way" - you should post the "correct" answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to play both of video and sound you need to create 2 source buffers . and as you said . you can play just one of them . so i guess you code is fine . so you need to create 2 buffers . like this

```
 my_media_source.addEventListener("sourceopen",function (){
    var video_source_buffer = my_media_source.addSourceBuffer(video_mimeCodec);
    var audio_source_buffer = my_media_source.addSourceBuffer(audio_mimeCodec);

     //.......

     video_source_buffer.appendBuffer(...);
     audio_source_buffer.appendBuffer(...);
 }
```

Now you can just buffer both of video and audio , keep in maind that MediaSource will not play you video antil it gets both of data . so for exemple if you buffered the first 5s from video and 3s from audio the player will stop at 3s

just keep your buffer equitable ;)

Comment: cant i handle video and audio simultaneously with some codec ?

Comment: When using this technique for video/webm and audio/webm, I receive an error for the second .addSourceBuffer: "Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': This MediaSource has reached the limit of SourceBuffer objects it can handle. No additional SourceBuffer objects may be added."

Comment: @TedPhillips can you show some of your code please?

Comment: Sorry, code no longer exists. Due to the buffer-count limit, I ended up muxing the video/audio and streaming that into a single sourceBuffer instead.